# gets() two dimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have trouble understanding the following code,

```
static char s[N][N];

int i = 0;
while( gets(s[i]) )
{ some loop, where i gets incremented }
```

considering the array is of N dimensions, then what happens when

```
gets(s)
```

is called? How can it store the entire string in the s[i] element? It feels like s[i] should be equal to the first char of the input, and not the entire string. And what happens when it loops with more input? The point is to have it stored as

```
[char, char, char, char]
[char, char, char, char, char]
[char, char, char, char, char, char]
... and so forth
```

which it seems like the code is currently doing. But I don't understand how.

EDIT #1

A lot of people suggested against using gets(), but why would gets() not be appropriate when there can be no illegal input and I want to store the characters as elements in an array and not as a string?

Comment: Don't use naked arrays and don't use naked pointers. In fact stay away from anything that's naked. Use `std::string`, `std::vector`, `std::array`, etc.

Comment: This code is copied from https://quickgrid.wordpress.com/2015/09/28/uva-problem-424-integer-inquiry-solution/. I am simply trying to understand the solution.

Comment: Don't use `gets` in C++.  It was deprecated and has since been removed.

Comment: Don't use gets() in C.

Comment: It seems though as many of these example solutions to uva questions use gets(), what would be an appropriate alternative? I've heard about fgets(), which is supposed to be safer - but it seems like a bit too much when you only want to solve a problem like this.

Comment: You can use `std::copy`.  You could also just use a `std::vector<std::string>` and read in the lines via `std::getline`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I would really want to understand how this works with gets() though, so I understand how to reimplement it and why also not to use it.

Comment: `gets` is inherently unsafe. It reads from standard input with no specified limit on how many characters it will read and store into a finite-sized array. `fgets(s[i], stdout, SIZE)` is safe if you've computed `SIZE` correctly. It differs from `gets` in that it leaves a trailing newline in the buffer. You cannot in general control what input will appear on `stdin`.

Answer (score 2):

The `s[i]` element is an array of characters since `s` is an array of arrays. An array of characters can be used to store a string by using a zero character (called a "nul") to mark the end.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
int multi_array[2][2] = {{2,3,4},
                         {7,8,9},
                         {1,5,0}};
```

`Array[n][m]`

Gets 
First position `Array[0][0]`

Second position `Array[0][1]`

Position 0,1 is 3

Position 1,2 is 9

Position 2,2, is 0

Answer (score 0):

The code above is storing the string but with a numbered index.
But storing that number index in the first dimension of the array.

Think of it in this way, I want to store 10 strings of max size of 256 char:

```
int main()
{
    char s[10][256];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        gets(s[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            cout << s[i] << endl;
    }
}

cout << s[1][2] << endl;
```

Note: for the last line in the code above it would output the second entry (we ordered everything from 0-9) and third character of the string at that entry.
Thus, if my entry was test2 then the output would be 's'.

Note: It would be incorrect to call gets(s) as it will not compile and is not the intention of the code.

gets() call has some features that can land you into a buffer overflow problem if the input is not monitored.